# Spark join two different data frames with different column names

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two data frames df1 & df2. Each data frame has different columns, but "id" is common column which can use to join these two data frames.

df1:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 |
| 1 | p2 |
| 2 | null |

df2:

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | c1 |
| 1 | c2 |
| 1 | c3 |
| 2 | c4 |

I need to get results as given below.

| id | price | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | c1 |
| 1 | p2 | c2 |
| 1 | null | c3 |
| 2 | null | c4 |

I can't use `df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)` as I am using a older spark version. Please suggest a solution.
I am using spark version2.4.8.

Comment: Please provide the spark version you are using and also update the tags to be more specific (eg: pyspark).

Comment: I am using spark version2.4.8 . using appache spark.

Comment: I am using spark version2.4.8 . I am using jav8. Not using python.<groupId>org.appache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>

Answer (score 1):

did you try:

> df1.join(df2, df1["id"] == df2["id"], "inner")

Comment: I tried, not working.

Comment: what error did you get?